# Razor Model Binding is blank

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have the following model:

```
public class ReadModel
{
     public string Name { get;set; }
}

public class EditViewModel
{
  public ReadModel Data { get;set;}
}
```

I then populate this in the controller and pass this to the view:

```
@model EditViewModel
<form asp-action="Edit">
     <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
         <div class="form-group">
             <label asp-for="Data.Name" class="control-label"></label>
             <input asp-for="Data.Name" class="form-control" />
              <span asp-validation-for="Data.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
         </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

However when the page displays there seems to be now errors but the label is blank and the input is also blank.

Can anyone help me hear?

**Update**

I can use the old method of

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Data.Name)
```

and i get a input textbox along with the data in the textbox

**Update**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Please post the **rendered** HTML.

Comment: Dai - when i f12 to developer tools and look at the html, the form is as above except it is surrounded with the body and other stuff like my menus etc.
I have read it is suppose to render differently but it isn't

Comment: Don't use F12. Use "View Source" and then copy and paste the entire `<form>` element. We're not interested in anything outside the `<form>` at this point.

Comment: Dai - it is showing the same thing

Comment: Right, so just select, copy, and paste _only_ the `<form>` element and its contents.

Comment: <form asp-action="Edit">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Data.Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Data.Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Data.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</form>

Comment: like i said the same thing as shown above

Comment: Don't post it in a comment, edit your question instead.

Comment: How do you set the data in backend? Are you sure your target framework is .net framework instead of .net core? Tag helper cannot be used in asp.net. You can check your target framework from your project file. If it is `netcoreappxxx` or `net5.0`/`net6.0`. It is .net core.

Comment: Rena - netcore3.1

Comment: If it is asp.net core, the tag helper should be work fine. How do you set the data? Are you sure you have set the data in the backend successfully?

Comment: Rena - Yes I am sure, I can use this to view the data in the view
var json = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
The issue was that I was inside an area and had not copied over the _ViewImports which has @addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.